# equivalent of tap operator that waits for completion

Tags: javascript, rxjs, puppeteer

I need to open a page on a URL, get the value of a variable, format it and return it.

I have this piece of code, which works :

```js
async function fetchVariable(browser, url) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const s = await page.evaluate(async () => Promise.resolve(myVariable));
    return s.replace(/\n/g, '');
}
```

I want to rewrite it without `await` because... why not. I tried this :

```js
function fetchVariable(browser, url) {
    return from(browser.newPage()).pipe(
            tap(page => page.goto(url)),
            mergeMap((page) => page.evaluate(async () => Promise.resolve(myVariable))),
            map((s) => s.replace(/\n/g, ''))
        ).toPromise();
}
```

I am stuck on this part : `tap(page => page.goto(url)),` because `tap` will not wait before passing to the next operator. And it results in this error message :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

I basically need to get the `page` issued by `browser.newPage()`, wait for the `page.gotoUrl(url)` to complete and forward the `page` to the next operator.

It seems that I am lacking a basic operator but I cannot see which one.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that the `goto` return a Promise, I'd suggest you to go all in over RxJS and convert everything

```js
function fetchVariable(browser, url) {
  return from(browser.newPage()).pipe(
    switchMap(page =>                               // <-- use `switchMap` here
      from(page.goto(url)).pipe(                    // <-- inner pipe to allow access to `page` variable
        switchMap(page => from(page.evaluate)),
        map(() => myVariable.replace(/\n/g, ''))
      )
    )   
  );
}
```

About `toPromise()`: [it's being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated) and will be removed by RxJS 8.

Comment: I don't like all those additional `from()` but you fingertipped the problem : `page.goto` returns a `Promise`. If I map just this one to an `Observable`, I can then use `delayWhen` instead of `tap` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do "switchTap".  Essentially perform an async side effect and wait for it to complete before continuing.

Instead of using `tap`, you could do `switchMap`, but return an observable that returns the original emission:

Here's a simplified example of the original situation:

```js
const myObservable$ = of('source #1').pipe(
  tap(() => myPromiseFn()),
  switchMap(i => of('source #2'))
);

// Order:
//  - source #1
//  - source #2
//  - promise
```

Solution mentioned above:

```js
const myObservable$ = of('source #1').pipe(
  switchMap(input => from(myPromiseFn()).pipe(
    map(() => input)
  )),
  switchMap(i => of('source #2')),
);

// Order:
//  - source #1
//  - promise
//  - source #2
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71799212?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts).